# How to load previously stored svm classifier?

Tags: c++, opencv, load, save, svm

I'm working with openCV SVM in Visual Studio. (OpenCV 2.4.4.0)

I trained it:

```
mySVM.train(trainingDataMat, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params);
```

Saved it:

```
mySVM.save("classifier.xml");
```

I'm loading it like this:

```
CvSVM mySVM1;
mySVM1.load("C:\classifier.xml");
mySVM1.predict(testingDataMat0,result0);
```

And i want to use in other project. But when i try to load classifier this error bumps all the time:

```
"Bad argument (The SVM should be trained first) in CvSVM::predict"
```

Path is correct, and .xml seems correctly stored.

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong or where the problem might be?

classifier.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<my_svm type_id="opencv-ml-svm">
  <svm_type>C_SVC</svm_type>
  <kernel><type>RBF</type>
    <gamma>5.0625000000000009e-001</gamma></kernel>
  <C>2.5000000000000000e+000</C>
  <term_criteria><epsilon>2.2204460492503131e-016</epsilon>
    <iterations>100</iterations></term_criteria>
  <var_all>3</var_all>
  <var_count>3</var_count>
  <class_count>2</class_count>
  <class_labels type_id="opencv-matrix">
    <rows>1</rows>
    <cols>2</cols>
    <dt>i</dt>
    <data>
      -1 1</data></class_labels>
  <sv_total>10</sv_total>
  <support_vectors>
    <_>
      9.09866020e-002 5.56291997e-001 2.43510995e-002</_>
    <_>
      9.46519971e-001 2.94328004e-001 2.08841003e-002</_>
    <_>
      1. 3.68389994e-001 1.15272999e-002</_>
    <_>
      9.41470027e-001 3.73109013e-001 1.25126000e-002</_>
    <_>
      1. 2.23776996e-001 9.57737025e-003</_>
    <_>
      4.68845010e-001 3.62690985e-002 9.11400989e-002</_>
    <_>
      7.98106015e-001 2.73550004e-002 9.26491022e-002</_>
    <_>
      7.02144980e-001 3.98130007e-002 9.00894031e-002</_>
    <_>
      4.99359012e-001 4.31513004e-002 8.61563012e-002</_>
    <_>
      7.39947975e-001 4.39946018e-002 9.60593969e-002</_></support_vectors>
  <decision_functions>
    <_>
      <sv_count>10</sv_count>
      <rho>-5.7845965027809154e-001</rho>
      <alpha>
        2.5000000000000000e+000 2.5000000000000000e+000
        1.4641912158132706e+000 2.5000000000000000e+000
        2.5000000000000000e+000 -1.4641912158132708e+000
        -2.5000000000000000e+000 -2.5000000000000000e+000
        -2.5000000000000000e+000 -2.5000000000000000e+000</alpha>
      <index>
        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</index></_></decision_functions></my_svm>
</opencv_storage>
```

Comment: Are you sure that train function returns `true`?

Comment: Yes, cause when I do mySVM.predict after training i get correct results. (and I've checked function flag)

Comment: You said it gives error during load but in the error line it says `CvSVM::predict`. Maybe you need to train again after loading? If it is not that, I need to see your full code, train, save and load parts.

Comment: it gives error in predict function because i want to use loaded classifier which isn't properly loaded (parameters aren't loaded). I don't want to train it again in other function, i just want to load trained parameters so i can use them for prediction. All code needed is above i added classifier.xml, maybe some mistake in storing occourd.

Comment: Hi I am hitting the same issue. How did you work around it?

Comment: My problem was in wrong type of slashes. Windows based systems use the backslash as an escape character, resulting in unwanted behavior. Therefore people need to type double slashes to undo the escape operation. i just used front slash  "C:/classifier.xml" and it works

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found that in SVM codes ,at least in OpenCV, predict function uses the same kernel witch is used in train function to determine input class. So when you run predict separately it doesn't know what kind of kernel should it uses. So, I think running train function exactly before predict function is avoidable.