# Object Serialization in C++ for storing the OpenCV's SVM object [OpenCV 3.1.0]

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, file-storage, object-serialization

So it is common knowledge that due to a bug in OpenCV when you try to load a non-linear kernel SVM after saving it you get an error.

Refer here for more:
[OpenCV 3.1.0: Save and load trained SVMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108811/opencv-3-1-0-save-and-load-trained-svms?rq=1)

People HAVE gotten the SVM to load but were unable to obtain the same result (classifier data was corrupted after loading). I tried testing this by writing my own svmloader function.

```
Ptr<SVM> svmloader(const String& filepath)
{
    FileStorage fs;
    fs.open(filepath, FileStorage::READ);

    Ptr<SVM> svm = Algorithm::read<SVM>(fs.getFirstTopLevelNode());
    return svm;
}
```

This works but I can as of now confirm that I've tested model pre and post loading and the results seem worse post-loading. That is after you train a classifier and you test it, it will be fine but if you save it and load it again it will get effed up.

So I think I want to use C++'s Object serialization to solve this problem. How can I write arbitary objects to a file and then read from that file?

**Also can someone confirm if the above bug has been fixed in OpenCV 3.2.0 I COULD NOT FIND ANYTHING IN THE RELEASENOTES**

Any help is GREATLY APPRECIATED folks

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp#L1611

You'll find that there is a clear() called every time you call cv::ml::SVM::trainAuto or cv::ml::SVM::train()